# An index error occurs the moment a face is detected

Tags: python

'''

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

# iniciate id counter
id = 0

# names related to ids: example ==> Marcelo: id=1,  etc
names = ['None', 'Marcelo', 'Paula', 'Ilza', 'Z', 'W']

# Initialize and start realtime video capture
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3, 640)  # set video widht
cam.set(4, 480)  # set video height

# Define min window size to be recognized as a face
minW = 0.1 * cam.get(3)
minH = 0.1 * cam.get(4)

while True:

    ret, img = cam.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, -1)  # Flip vertically

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.2,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(int(minW), int(minH)),
    )

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])

        # Check if confidence is less them 100 ==> "0" is perfect match 
        if (confidence < 100):
            id = names[id]
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
        else:
            id = "unknown"
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))

        cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x + 5, y - 5), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x + 5, y + h - 5), font, 1, (255, 255, 0), 1)

    cv2.imshow('camera', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff  # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
    if k == 27:
        break

# Do a bit of cleanup
print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

'''

The above personal face identification program encountered the following issues:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\OpenCV-Face-Recognition-master\OpenCV-Face-Recognition-master\FacialRecognition\03_face_recognition.py", line 59, in <module>
    id = names[id]
IndexError: list index out of range"
```

Is this a problem with the training data, or is there something wrong with the code itself?

Comment: what's the id value in that moment? do a print before call names[id], also i'm not sure using id as variable is a good idea, given that's also a keyword of python

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm still very bad at python lists and I don't know where to put that command to check the id value.

Comment: just between these 2 lines:  `if (confidence < 100):` and `id = names[id]`. and if you use id anywhere else also print it

Comment: I think that your problem is that you maybe are using id as as number but you assign another thing. you are doing `id = names[id]`.. maybe you can use another var name: like ` detectedName = names[id]` then you have to change the name also in `putText`

Comment: Typing print(id) after (confidence<100) gave me the result "24" referring to the 24th image data.

Comment: shouldn't id be a number in len(names) ? that's your problem your names array have 6 possible values and you're trying to access to the number 24!. I can't find LBPHrecognizer documentation, but it's returning you something else that's not an id in the list of names... maybe you using the wrong trainer.yml ? one trained with more faces or something like that? I cant help anymore cause I don't have much idea of face recognition. sorry